# Error using colSds; error while loop across lists

Tags: r, loops

I have the following list:

```html
d1<-data.frame(y1=c(34,56,89,45),y2=c(42,54,68,25),y3=c(253,547,586,258),y4=c(233,537,554,258))
d2<-data.frame(y1=c(37,26,14,67),y2=c(65,54,43,23),y3=c(243,577,516,125),y4=c(267,527,567,368))
d3<-data.frame(y1=c(35,24,14,58),y2=c(65,51,43,21),y3=c(267,527,567,368),y4=c(243,577,516,125))
d4<-data.frame(y1=c(34,23,13,36),y2=c(65,55,44,24),y3=c(233,537,554,258),y4=c(253,547,586,258))
lst <- list(d1,d2,d3,d4)
```

My intention is to obtain different data frames with the means and sd of certain columns for each of the elements of the list. The first problem came when trying to use colSds to obtain the sd.

```html
W.mean<-list()
W.sd<-list()
for (i in ids){
  W.mean<-lapply(lst, function(i) colMeans(i[,c(1,2,4)],na.rm=TRUE))
  W.sd<-lapply(lst, function(i) colSds(i[,c(1,2,4)],na.rm = TRUE))
}
```

As soon as I run this script I obtain the folowing error:

Error in colVars(x, rows = rows, cols = cols, ...) : 
  Argument 'x' must be a matrix or a vector.

The mean function still working so I have a new list with all the means (W.mean)

Now I want to create separete data.frame with just the means (would also include de sd, but I need to make it work)

```html
for (i in c("d1","d2","d3","d4")){
  df<-get(i)
  df<-data.frame(t(W.mean[[i]]))
  assign(paste0(i,"mean"), df)
}
```

However I get a new error: Error in t.default(W.mean[[i]]) : argument is not a matrix

can someone help me to fix the errors? TAHNKS

Comment: Don't put R code into java/html blocks. Also, you ought to include library(matrixStats) or wherever you got the non-base functions.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because `colSds` work on `matrix` and not on `data.frame`.  According to the `Description` from `?colSds`

> Description - Standard deviation estimates for each row (column) in a
>   matrix.

```
lapply(lst, function(i) colSds(i[, c(1,2, 4)], na.rm = TRUE))
```

> Error in colVars(x, rows = rows, cols = cols, ...) :    Argument 'x'
>   must be a matrix or a vector.

---

Therefore, convert the 'data.frame' to 'matrix' and it should work fine

```
lapply(lst, function(i) colSds(as.matrix(i[, c(1,2, 4)]), na.rm = TRUE))
#[[1]]
#[1]  23.76272  18.24600 173.64427

#[[2]]
#[1]  22.70095  17.91415 139.72682

#[[3]]
#[1]  18.89224  18.40290 216.20110

#[[4]]
#[1]  10.66146  17.56891 180.27202
```

---

Also, the `for` loop in

```
for(i in ids) {

 }
```

seems to be unnecessary if the intention is just to loop over the `list` of `data.frame` and get the `colMeans` and `colSds`.  Also, we can do this in a single `lapply` call instead of multiple `lapply`

```
res1 <- lapply(lst, function(i) t(cbind(Mean = colMeans(i[, c(1,2, 4)], 
        na.rm = TRUE), Sds = colSds(as.matrix(i[, c(1,2, 4)]), na.rm = TRUE))))
```

and it can be converted to a single dataset by `rbind`ing the contents

```
do.call(rbind, res1)
```